# Does anyone know a Good real time voice changer for Linux? (Specifically Ubuntu)

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

I've been looking for a while to try and find a real time voice changer for Linux (Specifically Ubuntu). I usually edit my voice in Audacity when I want to change it but recently I have found myself in the need of a real time voice changer. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You can start with the [`pyvoicechanger` python script](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger).

Or you can use `sox` and piping to achieve a similar result using:

```
 sox -d -d pitch -700 contrast 100 echo 0.8 0.88 6 0.4
```

For full list of `sox` sound effects:  [SoX - Sound eXchange Wiki: EFFECTS](https://sox.fandom.com/wiki/EFFECTS)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lyrebird](https://github.com/constcharptr/lyrebird)

It's a simple and powerful voice changer for Linux, written in GTK 3.
And it works just by switching it on and off

Answer (score 3):

The only one left (Working properly) is EasyEffects.

**URL** - https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects

And you can install it on ubuntu like so:

`sudo apt install easyeffects`

or using Flatpak from here https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.wwmm.easyeffects

Do remember that starting with Ubuntu 23.04, you have to do the following before installing Flatpak packages

`sudo apt install flatpak`