# Finding a functioning voice changer for Discord on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording, sox

I've been trying to find (or make) a voice changer for a project I have with some friends for a tabletop gameover Discord, which includes role-playing. Thing is, I can't find any real-time voice modifier/changer/modulator that works on Ubuntu, and can also be detected in Discord as a viable Input Device. Reading other forum posts, I've tried the following:

- [pyvoicechanger](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger), which only works on pitch, and Discord can't detect.
- Jack Rack, which Discord doesn't support at the moment (See [this issue](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360035393592-Jack-audio-support-in-Linux-or-at-least-ALSA))
- And finally, according to these two already asked questions ([one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091606/does-anyone-know-a-good-real-time-voice-changer-for-linux-specifically-ubuntu) and [two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421947/is-there-a-way-to-modulate-my-voice-on-the-fly)), sox.

The last one is the only one I haven't confirmed as "not working" since, according to the mentioned [seconds post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421947/is-there-a-way-to-modulate-my-voice-on-the-fly), it requires outputting the audio to a "null sink", [which neither Chrome nor any other Ubuntu recorder/app detects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK1LK.png)

So, what I want to ask is: ***Is there an alternative to voice changer, being manual modulators using chorus, pitch, etc; or simple voice changers using defined settings ("robot", "giant", "helium voice", etc) that can work with different apps in Ubuntu?*** (Or at least with Discord)