# Looking for real time voice changer through Linux?

Tags: boot

I am looking for a real time voice changer for my Chromebook on Linux.

Does anyone know which one I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know a Good real time voice changer for Linux? (Specifically Ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091606/does-anyone-know-a-good-real-time-voice-changer-for-linux-specifically-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Install some packages:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol libsox-fmt-pulse sox
```

Check your voice in normal mode by loading module-loopback:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=100
```

Unload module-loopback to stop listening your voice:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

Use [the next command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148185/925971) to change your voice in real time and listen to it:

```
sox -d -d pitch -700 contrast 100 echo 0.9 0.9 5 0.6
```

Change pitch, contrast and echo settings the way you like. And then you could use these settings in some programs like skype selecting them on pavucontrol's **Recording** tab:

- `pactl load-module module-null-sink`
- `sox -t pulseaudio default -t pulseaudio null pitch -700 contrast 100 echo 0.9 0.9 5 0.6`
- `pavucontrol`

[image]

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/425544/925971)